# how to fix header and footer in php file

Tags: php, css

I am Developing a code using php . In which I am importing two files (header.php and footer.php) in another php file index.php. 
 Now I want that header.php and footer.php should be fixed while scrolling horizontally. can you suggest me the code. I am using the following code

```
Header.php
 code here
footer.php
code here
```

index.php

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
 welcome to index file 
 welcome to index file 
 welcome to index file 

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

In this file index.php, I want that header and footer should be fixed while scrolling horizontally     and others css should also not be disturbed.

Comment: First You need to understand PHP has got nothing to do with it.And  Its a CSS part

Comment: give the solution if you have ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.,

```
 <div id="header">
    <?PHP include_once('header.php');?>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
    welcome to index file
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <?PHP include_once('foo.php');?>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#header{position:fixed;top:0px;}
#footer{position:fixed;bottom:0px;}
```

or

```
header.php 
<div id ="header"></div><div id="content">
footer.php
</div><div id="footer"></div>

index.php
<?PHP include_once('header.php');?>
 content here.,
<?PHP include_once('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: header and footer are fixed but scroll is working till top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your solucion is ok.
only i recomend use something like this:

```
<div id="header">
<?PHP include_once('header.php');?>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
here is my html content
</div>
<div id="footer">
<?PHP include_once('foo.php');?>
</div>
```

the use of `include_once` is for not repeat  the `include` of some file
and with a good css obtains a excelent layout

Comment: can you suggest me the css for header , footer and wrap div also

Comment: @adeshsingh I have added an answer with css..i can help u if you have further doubts.. :)

Comment: scroll is working till top and bottom but i want scroll should work   from header below and footer top

Comment: check http://latraiciondesargeras.x10.mx, one of my websites, try  the html and css code of layout

Answer (score 0):

use `HTML5` and use  `include_once`

```
<header>
<?PHP include_once('header.php');?>
</header>
<div id="wrap">
here is my html content
</div>
<footer>
<?PHP include_once('foo.php');?>
</footer>
```

Here is just a sample [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0gp01Lm6/)

```
html,body{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
header{
    background:Green;
    height:50px;
}
footer{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background:Red;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, just put the following attribute:
 `position:fixed;` and that should do the trick.